# how to install mysql-server Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I am using windows 10 and installed Ubuntu from the windows app store. In the terminal I type sudo apt-get install mysql-server.

I have tried multiple guides of making sure I removed all Sql installs and files that could have been installed already. The strange thing is I just downloaded Ubuntu and never had mysql on the system. I continue to get the below error.

[Error displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6yyA.png)

Setup Explained: 
I just went to the windows store and downloaded the canonical software. Unfortunately, I dont know much about this linux. I just downloaded and I can just open up the ubuntu exe. This may be the root of my problem. Its a windows app.

Comment: This looks like a file system permission issue. Normally the installation is not an issue, so chances are this is an issue with your setup. Could you please explain in more detail how you actually set things up? You install Linux _inside_ a running MS-Windows system? How is that meant to work? Is that a virtual machine? A container? How does it access the file system?

Comment: I would recommend to install in a bona fide linux physical machine or VM. What kind of setup is this?